# Preserving image size when rotating

Tags: matlab, image-processing, rotation

Does somebody know how I can rotate an image, then rotate it back, without losing index information? Which means, I want to rotate an image, perform a certain operation, and then rotate it back. Because when you rotate an image, the size changes, and it gets even bigger when you rotate it back. I would like this second rotation to return the image to its original size. How can I accomplish that?

```
I_rot = imrotate(I,45);
%size changes I_rot has different size than I
I_rot_back = imrotate(I_rot,-45);
%I_rot_back should have the same dimensions as I.
```

Comment: 'when you rotate an image the size changes' is in direct disagreement with 'stays that size when rotating back'. Why does your image change size when rotating, and then doesn't change size when rotating?

Comment: I have reworded your question a bit, please change it back or [edit] it further if I misinterpreted your question.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation to `imrotate`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrotate.html#buxwj90-1-bbox) shows a 4th, optional, argument, which allows you to maintain the image sizes:

```
I_rot = imrotate(I,45,'bicubic','crop'); % the default method is 'nearest', but 'bucubic' is much better!
I_rot_back = imrotate(I_rot,-45,'bicubic','crop');
```

However, this causes you to lose the information in the corners of the image. It would be better to allow the first rotation to increase the size of the image, so that all information is preserved, and then after the second rotation to crop the image to its original size. You can use [`imcrop`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imcrop.html) for this:

```
isz = [size(I,2),size(I,1)];  % note the reversed indices!
I_rot = imrotate(I,45,'bicubic');
I_rot_back = imrotate(I_rot,-45,'bicubic');
osz = [size(I_rot_back,2),size(I_rot_back,1)];
I_rot_back = imcrop(I_rot_back, [(osz-isz)/2, isz]);
```